# std::function and shared_ptr

Tags: c++, std-function, c++-loki

I have been using Loki's Functor for a while and I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599849/lokis-functor-with-variadic-templates) about it (still unanswered...)
I have been told to use std::function, but I prefer Loki's implementation of Functor since it also work with all sorts of pointers as parameters (e.g. std::shared_ptr).

```
struct Toto
{
    void foo( int param )
    {
        std::cout << "foo: " << param << std::endl;
    }
};

int
main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
    std::shared_ptr<Toto> ptr = std::make_shared<Toto>();

    Loki::Functor<void, LOKI_TYPELIST_1(int)> func( ptr, &Toto::foo );

    func(1);
}
```

Is there a way to do so with std::function ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `std::bind`.

```
auto func = std::bind(&Toto::foo, ptr, std::placeholders::_1);
```

here, `func` will be deduced to type, that was returned from `std::bind` or if you don't like `auto` you can use (and you want to use `std::function`)

```
std::function<void(int)> func = std::bind(&Toto::foo, 
ptr, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Here `std::function` will be constructed from result of `std::bind`.
`ptr` will be copied to some object returned from `std::bind`, however you can use `std::ref`/`std::cref` if you don't want copies.

Comment: I don't think this works with `shared_ptr`, and if it did, it wouldn't re-evaluate the pointer at each call. Also, note that these one-liners do completely different things: `bind()` does not return a `std::function`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter it works with `shared_ptr`. Why it should reevaluate?

Comment: Ah, I missed the subtlety of the INVOKE concept. Indeed it makes a copy and dereferences every time. I was thinking in terms of conversion. Still, please note that `auto` stores a statically-dispatched bind object, not a dynamically-dispatched `std::function`, and those are completely different things.

Comment: @Potatoswatter it works like `Loki::Functor`, nothing special. It can do copy, it can not.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks a lot. It will start using this from now. Still... I would have loved to understand how to make `Loki::Functor` work with variadic templates. Thank you again !

Comment: @Athanase So you want to use `Loki::Functor` to construct a functor and then use it as a `std::function`? Try to simply assign it to `std::function`, it might work.

Comment: @leemes I wanted to modify the implementation of `Loki::Functor` to make it work with variadic templates because right now there is a lot of uneeded template specialization, and a limited number of arguments. This is just a personnal programming excercise...

Comment: @Athanase it's not so simple. But however, if you read more about variadic templates - you can do this. Loki is writed on typelist concept, so, you should rewrite it on concept of variadic templates.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `std::bind`, an option is to use a lambda function, resulting in even smaller code and I personally find it more intuitive:

```
auto func = [&ptr](int p){ ptr->foo(p); };
```

or without `auto`:

```
std::function<void(int)> func = [&ptr](int p){ ptr->foo(p); };
```

But this only works if the function to be called is fixed (i.e. `&Toto::foo` was not passed dynamically). If not, it's still possible with a lambda but you need a slightly different syntax and `std::bind` might be more attractive again.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::bind`.

```
struct Toto
{
    void foo( int param )
    {
        std::cout << "foo: " << param << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Toto> ptr = std::make_shared<Toto>();
    std::function< void(int) > func( std::bind( &Toto::foo,
        std::bind( [ptr] () { return ptr.get(); } ),
        std::placeholders::_1
    ) );

    func( 1 );
}
```

[Live demo.](http://ideone.com/DJ5Yvf)

Edit: The inner `bind` with a lambda expression is actually unnecessary, but I'll just leave this here as illustrative of more advanced usage.